# A photo on an old software package box

Tags: italy, identify-this

[image]

I stumbled on this photo, it's on the box of an **old** issue of a software map of Italy. I *suppose* the location portrayed is in Italy, anyone?

---

"location portrayed" means that I'm interested in what is shown in the picture (a hill-top village) and not as much in the location from which the photo was taken.

Comment: It sort of looks familiar to me. It could have been a stage-finish in the Giro years ago. I'm sort of reminded of arial footage of the landscape while watching the cycling on TV.

Comment: @tonny Exactly: this May the 6th stage ascended to the top before reaching the finish line in Ascoli Piceno.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The other answers are right, it's [Castelluccio di Norcia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Castelluccio,_Norcia) in Umbria, Italy, seen from a hill southwest of it called Monte Valletta.

There's a [Google Street View photo](https://www.google.com/maps/@42.8296102,13.1993259,3a,75y,116.36h,81.24t/data=!3m8!1e1!3m6!1sAF1QipNAFzHnPOtvrLYjU1TyJe-4A1MtDwX5bGlHkdm0!2e10!3e11!6shttps:%2F%2Flh5.googleusercontent.com%2Fp%2FAF1QipNAFzHnPOtvrLYjU1TyJe-4A1MtDwX5bGlHkdm0%3Dw203-h100-k-no-pi-0-ya301.69977-ro-0-fo100!7i8704!8i4352) by Gabriele Lorenzini which is taken very close to the location of your picture:

[image]

Comment: Of the previous answers, one is right but unsubstantiated, the other one is incorrect (it's Monte Veletta with 2 "e"'s, as you correctly wrote) and incomplete, because I am not interested in the shot location but in the (main) subject of the photo.  So, I'd say yours is the first correct, complete, substantiated answer and I could accept it if the poster of the first correct answer won't succeed in providing an explanation of their answer. PS: It's Castelluccio **di Norcia**, Italy has plenty of other "Castelluccio"s :-)

Comment: Thank you for the correction. Spelling is indeed important, you might end up in an entirely different part of Italy...

Answer (score 39):

Yes, that is in **Monte Veletta** in Italy. The original picture is this one:

[image]

Location:

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127124/discussion-on-answer-by-xoce--epeupa--a-photo-on-an-old-software-package-box).

Comment: @gboffi you can suggest an [edit] to correct the spelling, like so: https://travel.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/140414

Answer (score 6):

It's Castelluccio di Norcia as seen from Monte Veletta, probably before the 2016 earthquake.